# Android OpenCv: Edit ImageView Mat without Reassigning

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to load a Mat into an ImageView, do image processing on the Mat, and show the processed Mat without having to load it into the ImageView again.

Is this possible? I feel like repeatedly converting the Mat to a Bitmap and then loading the Bitmap into the ImageView is overkill, especially since I need to edit small sections of the Mat continually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenCV Mat is a different representation of the bitmap data than the bitmap representation that ImageView uses. Before becoming too concerned about the performance of repeatedly converting from Mat to ImageView, you should determine if there actually is a performance issue. If there is, there are other techniques that you could use to accelerate the drawing of pixels to the screen, but you will continue to have to convert from a Mat to some other memory representation.

If your processing work can be broken down into subsections of the image, you can only update a section of the bitmap, but once again, you should make sure there is actually a performnce issue before you prematurely optimize.